# How can i use different cloud created by openstack, cloustack, vrealise?

Tags: cloud, vmware

I am in dilemma that i had created cloud using OpenStack in my firm and started using it in application by its SDK , but its api are not same as of AWS. But now my firm wants a commercial cloud provider for private cloud setup like vmware and others.

So will i be able to use vmware vrealise and vlcoud suite? , did they provide the api like as of AWS or openstack.
Or will i be able to deploy some Paas like cloudfoundry or they already had there own ?.

I learned that vrealise provide api for the vmware management only.

Answer (score 0):

There's a handful of options for you to look into:

- OpenStack Integration on VMware: https://www.vmware.com/products/openstack.html
- Several Cloud Foundry solutions integrate with vSphere: https://pivotal.io/platform
- VMware Cloud on AWS: https://cloud.vmware.com/vmc-aws